# How to use "or" operator in Typescript with Omit<>?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This code:

```
type WithOr = {a:string} & ({b?:true, c?:never} | {b?:false, c:number})
type Ommited = Omit<WithOr, 'a'>
const m1: Ommited = {b: true};
const m2: WithOr = {...m1, a: 'a'}
```

will end up with error:

```
...
Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'.
...
```

It seems like Omit is throwing out the "or" logic.

Is there some other way how can I re-use my complicated type using Omit (with "or" in it), but not redefining everything?

Here is [running playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgeQE5QLxQN4EMBcAzsKnAHYDmAvlAGRQAU2ARgPz4kCuEANFAMbsyEAG4RUNAD442+AGa4ANoV4D8ZTgFtm4qgEoAUKEhRkmzQggATTKYvAAPPCRo+AclxuAfAYP8A9mTEUJoAjPh29ta2LBFcEFQA3H6BwZoATBHOKOhY2AB0hWF8BFAeblS+AUH+ihD5iv4UDJoQhIS4FBB6iUA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how `Omit` works. Here's how it is defined in [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/038d95144d8b93c2799d1732181c89c3d84362d5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1469):

```js
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

`Exclude<keyof T, K>` produces a union of all keys except the ones you pass as `K`. So in your example that would be `'b' | 'c'`.

`Pick` then uses a mapped type to iterate over these keys and create a new object type:

```js
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

Because of this the type gets "flattened". In case of `b`, `T['b']` returns `true | false | undefined` which TypeScript simplifies to `boolean | undefined`.

And you end up with:

```js
type Ommited = {
    b?: boolean | undefined;
    c?: number | undefined;
}
```

---

I think the best thing you can do here is extract the "or" part into a named type and re-use that:

```js
type OrPart = {b?:true, c?:never} | {b?:false, c:number}
type WithOr = {a:string} & OrPart
const m1: OrPart = {b: true};
const m2: WithOr = {...m1, a: 'a'}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgBQIZ2FAvFA3gIwPwBcwcArhADRQDGhAdhAG4RwC+UAPtvgQGZIA2AZwrUCtEgFsczFgChQkKAHUAlsAAW8DNiQFBxFbQDmbAGSxEKYLKoB7WvqgSAjAQvJU23G+JkWAbht7RwkAJjdVDS1MLAA6eJdKXSgAciQUliA)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I had to create `OrPart` & `MyPart`, where I use Omit on `MyPart` and it works then, cool